# How to fix "An NSManagedObject of class 'ClassName' must have a valid NSEntityDescription" when using CoreData from a framework

Tags: ios, core-data

I have separated my Data Access Layer (DAL) in a framework in order to be able to use it in both the app and its Today widgets. I set up everything and it compiled but at runtime when I tried to create a `NSPersistentContainer` the app crashed with the infamous `An NSManagedObject of class 'ClassName' must have a valid NSEntityDescription`.

What I tried:

- checking if the name of the persistent container is the same as the data model
- [selecting `Current Product Module` for the model class module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38306920/2781218)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What helped:

- checking all targets that will use `CoreData` for the `xcdatamodeld` file

To do this:

1. Select the `xcdatamodeld` file in `Project Navigator`
2. Open `Utilities` on the right side
3. Open `File Inspector`
4. Check all needed targets under `Target Membership`

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue while moving the data layer to a framework. The issue is `NSPersistentContainer` looks for an entity description in the main bundle by default, unless we create a custom subclass.

So the solution is to create a custom subclass of `NSPersistentContainer` in the embedded framework, and use it instead of the parent class. It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In My case it was fixed when I changed

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Your Project Name Here")
```

to

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Your Data Model Name Here")
```

In Appdelegate.Swift