# managedObjectContext in Swift 3

Tags: core-data, swift3, macos-sierra

I want to work through [this example code](https://www.brandpending.com/2016/01/14/using-core-data-in-a-swift-cocoa-app-to-populate-an-nstableview/) in which Swift and CoreData is used to create a table. However, using Swift 3 I fail to get it to work. Most importantly, I cannot properly replace the line

```
// set up the NSManagedObjectContext
  let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
```

even though I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956720/how-to-create-managedobjectcontext-using-swift-3-in-xcode-8) (which however is iOS not OS X). How can I replace that piece of code which produces the error message `Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedContext'`?

Comment: Have you checked the option "Use Core Data" when you created the new project? It's required because it adds the code for the Core Data Stack in AppDelegate.

Comment: @vadian Yes I did. But: I also checked document based app, unit testing and UI tests. And I notice that no code is in the AppDelegate when I check everything in contrast to only checking CoreData...

Comment: That's weird. File a bug. To solve your problem create a new project with only Core Data checked and copy&paste the Core Data Stack into your document based project.

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 3 in macOS**

```
let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
```

The error you provided says `'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedContext'` instead of `'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedObjectContext'`, which would lead me to assume you just need to fix your syntax.

**Swift 3 in iOS 10**

Core Data needs at least 3 things to work:

1. A managed object model
2. A persistent store coordinator
3. And a managed object context

Put those three things together and you get the Core Data Stack.

When iOS 10 came out, a new object was introduced called the [NSPersistentContainer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentcontainer?language=objc) which encapsulates the core data stack.

How to create the container object is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956720/how-to-create-managedobjectcontext-using-swift-3-in-xcode-8).

`managedObjectContext` is now a property called `viewContext`, accessed via:

```
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedObjectContext = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

A helpful article is [What's New in Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html), but if that reading seems a little too heavy, this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/242/) does a great job of explaining this topic.

Answer (score 8):

`AppDelegate` has below members only

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

so use

```
 let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! appDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

This will work fine

Answer (score 5):

For macOS and Swift 3.1

```
let moc: NSManagedObjectContext = (NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Answer (score 4):

I swift 3 you can get managedContext set by this code:

```
  let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Comment: Works for Swift4