# NSPersistentContainer is only available in 10.0 or newer : error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, ios10

It's because My deployment target is less than 10.

how to resolve for deployment target lower to 10.0 ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of solutions is to use https://github.com/inspace-io/INSPersistentContainer

and add

```
typealias NSPersistentContainer         = INSPersistentContainer
typealias NSPersistentStoreDescription  = INSPersistentStoreDescription
```

to your file where you want to use

Comment: not the best solution (to use a third-party lib), but the quickest! haha thanks!

Comment: It's a very bad habit to include an additional lib for a conditions that might need about 8 lines of own code.

Answer (score 3):

*Not available* means not available.

There are two options:

- Use only the *old* `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator / NSManagedObjectModel` pattern.
- Use both patterns and write the code with availability checking `if #available(iOS 10, *)`

Comment: These are the only options. There's another discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956720/how-to-create-managedobjectcontext-using-swift-3-in-xcode-8 where you can find ways to use the second approach.

Answer (score 3):

**Before iOS 10**

you could access the NSManagedObjectContext directly from `AppDelegate.h`

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
// Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store
// coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error
// conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
if coordinator == nil {
    return nil
}
var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
return managedObjectContext
```

([Original code](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-1/))

**from iOS 10 and newer**

this changed and the `NSManagedObjectContext` has been moved into the `PersistentContainer` into the attribute **viewContext**

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
/*
 The persistent container for the application. This implementation
 creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
 application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
 error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
*/
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "")
...
...
```

([original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39867959/1141395))

So, you need to distinguish which version you're app is running on and then call the correct function. ManagedObjectContext inside AppDelegate or The ManagedObjectContext inside [PersistentContainer viewContext].

btw: Be careful with tutorials for versions before iOS 10.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `@available` tag like this:

`@available(iOS 10.0, *)
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = ...`

Comment: What does this mean in terms of running an app on say iOS 8? Can we still run it with iOS 8 this way? Thanks

Comment: You won't be able to run this code on iOS 8. Compiler won't let you run this code outside `if #available` if your deployment target is less than availability target for this code.

Comment: Yeah I found that out the hard way. As much as I don't like it, I had to switch back to the old way of using the core data stack. It works just fine for everything.