# undeclared type 'NSPersistenContainer'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm insert in my Xcode project (Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.2.1) a code into Appdelegate file to CoreData.

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
         */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ArduinoHomeKit")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                
                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
    
    func saveContext () {
        let context  = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
```

But I have an error on NSPersistentContainer.
The error is:

> could not infer type for 'persistentContainer'
>
> use of undeclared type 'NSPersistenContainer'

I think that this problem is because the code is for Swift 3.0 but I have used Swift 2.2
How can I fixed it?

Comment: Update Xcode / your code. Swift 3 and higher is the future.

Comment: To update at Swift 3.0 I must update Xcode?

Comment: Yes you have to.

Comment: Ok, I'm try to update my Xcode from 3 hours ago but I have the circle that run on Apple Store but the installation not start. Is too slow

Answer (score 3):

`NSPersistentContainer` was added in iOS 10. You are using Xcode 7.2.1 which means your Base SDK is iOS 9. Therefore `NSPersistentContainer` is an unknown class.

Use older examples for Core Data that existed prior to iOS 10 and `NSPersistentContainer`.

Or update to Xcode 8.3 and iOS 10 (which you really should do anyway). But if your Deployment Target is iOS 9 or earlier, you need to be aware that your app won't work on those device if you try to use `NSPersistentContainer`.

Comment: Ok, but what class I can use to iOS 9?

Comment: There are many Core Data examples out there that haven't been updated for iOS 10. Do some searching. You can also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39627078/1226963 for an example of supporting both the old and new way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the type NSPersistenContainer is indeed not declared anywhere. The type NSPersistentContainer is. So wherever you are trying to use NSPersistenContainer, use NSPersistentContainer instead.

Comment: None of posted code has that typo, just the 2nd error message. Probably a typo when posting the question.