# IOS Dev Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedObjectContext' Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am following a Udemy tutorial [Link](https://www.udemy.com/course/ios-9-swift-2-xcode-7-make-an-app-programming-code-ios9-dev/learn/lecture/3461630#questions/920550). This is my first time working with Core Data. This is what they have:

```
let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

this is what I have:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

I get this error:

> Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedObjectContext'

Can anyone point me in the right direction to understand if it is a syntax problem or did I not create something.

Comment: Are you sure you selected Core Data when you created the project?

Comment: Is the Core Data stack present in AppDelegate? When creating a new project you have to check `Use Core Data` to get the Core Data stack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create managedObjectContext using Swift 3 in Xcode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956720/how-to-create-managedobjectcontext-using-swift-3-in-xcode-8)

Comment: Yes, I have the 2 files Item+CoreDataClass.swift & Item+CoreDataProperties.swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’ve checked/ticked “Use Core Data” when setting up your project, you should have a “pre-installed” Core Data “stack” in your `AppDelegate` file, similar to that described in the Apple documentation titled “[Core Data Stack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/core_data_stack)”.

Your `AppDelegate` should contain code similar to that detailed in the Apple documentation titled “[Setting Up a Core Data Stack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/setting_up_a_core_data_stack)”, under the subheading “Initialize a Persistent Container”.

What it most likely does not include is a property for `managedObjectContext`. The error explains this.

My guess is that you need to add a property for `managedObjectContext` in your `AppDelegate` file, similar to this...

```
LINE 1
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
```

(Note that I’ve made this property an explicitly unwrapped optional `!`.)

Then set this when you return your `NSPersistentContainer`.

```
LINE 2
self.managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
```

These lines are placed as shown below...

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    ...

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!       //LINE 1

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {        
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)")
            }
        }

        self.managedObjectContext = container.viewContext   //LINE 2

        return container
    }()

    ... 
}
```